# Can the OS X unlock panel trigger a login hook similar to loginwindow?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, hook

I'd like to automatically run a shell script every time I authenticate onto my computer. However, all the info I can find about loginhook and Global LoginItems applies only when authenticating to "loginwindow," and not to the "unlock panel."

The unlock panel prompts for a password when waking up from sleep or from a locked screen.
Is there any way to trigger script execution after successfully unlocking the screen?

Comment: FYI this has been asked again here: http://superuser.com/questions/447154

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [SleepWatcher](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/mac/17579). It lets you execute Unix commands on wakeup. Not exactly what you are looking for, but still, it can help.